# Retrieving parameter from query string based on another string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

My app in Google Apps Script gets data from a form that I want to process.
The element `form` is received and contains the different parameters and values.

If I log the element `form` it looks like `{uid=11, tradingname=xxx, email=yyy}`

I can pick up the separate values by running `form.uid` or `form.tradingname` for example. But what I want is to pick up the parameters from the element `form` by referring to a String "uid" (because I get this value form the headers row of the spreadsheet).

Is there a simple way I can do this in one line, for example something like:

```
form.element["uid"]
```

So far I've only found difficult methods like https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/ and I would think that I should be able to do this in an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: use `form["uid"]`

Comment: Great, I knew it would be this easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $("#yourform").serializeArray() and then iterate to match "name" values you want